# How to execute pivot queries in JPA-Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, pivot-table

In MYSQL I have this query:

My table

```
    planning
    -------------------
    process_id (int)
    project_id (int)
    period (datetime)
    total_hour (double)
```

```
    SELECT process_id, project_id,
    sum( if (period="2013-04-01 00:00:00",total_hour,0)) as april,
    sum( if (period="2013-05-01 00:00:00",total_hour,0)) as may,
    sum( if (period="2013-06-01 00:00:00",total_hour,0)) as june
    FROM planning
    GROUP BY process_id,project_id;
```

I need convert this clausule SQL for use in JPA ?

Answer (score 6):

SQL to JPQL

```
SELECT p.process_id, p.project_id,
sum( case when p.period="2013-04-01 00:00:00" then p.total_hour else 0 end ) as april,
sum( case when p.period="2013-05-01 00:00:00" then p.total_hour else 0 end ) as may,
sum( case when p.period="2013-06-01 00:00:00" then p.total_hour else 0 end ) as june,
FROM Planning p
GROUP BY p.process_id, p.project_id;
```

But you can still use native queries too.

To map your resultset : you can map manually your resultset to a new bean (use dozer if you prefer), or you can use some @SqlResultSetMapping see [How to select multiple columns with the same name using JPA native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180214/how-to-select-multiple-columns-with-the-same-name-using-jpa-native-query)

Comment: How add the result set to new object (Example: PlanningExtractBean.class) because the origin Bean is diferent of the result set.