# hibernate criteria query self join and get specific columns and count with restrictions

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have one table of MonthlySubscriber in MySql:

```
CREATE TABLE  MonthlySubscriber (
 MobileNo varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 Month int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (MobileNo, Month)
 );
```

one mobile no can come multiple times in more than one month. So according to mobile no i have to join my table.

Requirment:

I want to self-join my table and want only MobileNo and Month from first table and and month from second table.
I want (count of all mobileNo and Month from first table and and month from second table) with order by and group by both from columns (Month from first table and and month from second table)

My MySql query:

```
 Select COUNT(t.MSI), t.Mon1 ,t.Mon2 from
 ( SELECT
     MonthlySubscriber.MobileNo as MSI,
     MonthlySubscriber.Month as Mon1,
     MonthlySubscriber.Month as Mon2
   FROM MonthlySubscriber as MonthlySubscriber
   LEFT JOIN MonthlySubscriber as MonthlySubscriber on
         (MonthlySubscriber.MobileNo = MonthlySubscriber.MobileNo )
   ORDER by MonthlySubscriber.Month
 )
 t GROUP BY t.Mon1, t.Mon2;
```

I want exactly same query in Hibernate criteria query.

Example

table

```
> MobileNo  || Month 
> 852335421 || 1 
> 852335421 || 2 
> 852335421 || 5
> 994534554 || 3 
> 924443443 || 4 
> 994534554 || 7
> 864645353 || 1
result should come like this
>count_of_mobileNos || month 1 || month 2
>   2               ||  1       || 1
>   1               ||  1       || 2
>   1               ||  1       || 5
>   1               ||  2       || 2
>   1               ||  2       || 5
>   1               ||  3       || 3
>   1               ||  3       || 7
>   1               ||  4       || 4
>   1               ||  5       || 5
>   1               ||  7       || 7
```

Note months are in integer from 1-12

Comment: Can you give sample data? and please make your question clear or can you please elaborate/show us what you want to achieve or output?

Comment: Sorry for bad way of questioning, actually this is my first question

Comment: What you are trying to do is a **[pivotal table/query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765446/how-to-execute-pivot-queries-in-jpa-hibernate)** but it is possible if you to create such query with referencing to the same query with 12 sub-queries which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(MobileNo),
count( case when m.Month=1 then m.Month else 0 end ) as Month 1,
count( case when m.Month=2 then m.Month else 0 end ) as Month 2,
count( case when m.Month=3 then m.Month else 0 end ) as Month 3,
.
.
.
count( case when m.Month=12 then m.Month else 0 end ) as Month 12
FROM MonthlySubscriber m
GROUP BY m.Month
```

Comment: can u this query in criteria, because I dont know about which database we have to use in future

Comment: That would be different question. You have to provide us more info regarding your java classes in hibernate criteria.