# JPA Query selecting only specific columns by using native query and without Custom Pojo

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to select only few columns from 3 different tables.

```
SELECT b.name,s.name,t.name 
FROM Q_BANK qb  
    INNER JOIN TOPIC t ON qb.TOPIC_ID=t.ID 
    INNER JOIN SUBJECT s ON s.ID=t.SUBJECT_ID 
    INNER JOIN BRANCH b ON b.ID=s.BRANCH_ID 
WHERE qb.Q_ID=123
```

Following is output in MySQL Workbench which is correct.

[image: This is correct output]

JPA Code is as follows

```
Query q=localEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT b.name,s.name,t.name 
FROM Q_BANK qb  INNER JOIN TOPIC t ON qb.TOPIC_ID=t.ID 
INNER JOIN SUBJECT s ON s.ID=t.SUBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN BRANCH b ON b.ID=s.BRANCH_ID
WHERE qb.Q_ID=:qId").setParameter("qId", questionId);
List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();
for (Object[] x : result) {
    for(Object y:x) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

And Output is as follows and it is not the expected output.

[image]

Comment: It looks fine. Can you debug or use System.out.print to find out the value of result.size()?

Comment: Ok, it seems if the fields have the same names, the first field will override the others. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180214/how-to-select-multiple-columns-with-the-same-name-using-jpa-native-query. Can you change the query and use alias like this Query q=localEntityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT b.name ,s.name as subjectName,t.name as topicName...

Comment: Thanks , that link was right it is working now.